# Please help me convert this piece of XAML code to C# (DataBinding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Im trying to add a bunch of textboxes dynamically, however I'm having trouble converting the following databinding to C#:

```
{Binding Path=Oppervlak,
         Source={StaticResource Gegevens},
         ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
         Mode=OneWayToSource}
```

I have several static textboxes with the above binding, however now I want to add more textboxes with the same binding from C# code, what I have currently is:

```
Binding RijBinding = new Binding();
RijBinding.Source = new GegevensValidatie();
RijBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Oppervlak");
RijBinding.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
RijBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
RijBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
RijTextbox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, RijBinding);
```

Gegevens is a resource defined by:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <src:GegevensValidatie x:Key="Gegevens"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Im using this as a way to verify that the user input is the proper format.

EDIT:
Fixed by changing:

```
RijTextbox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, RijBinding);
```

to

```
RijTextbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, RijBinding);
```

Comment: Hopefully that binding is on a textbox in an ItemsControl template? I don't feel there is enough information here to help. What exactly are you trying to convert to C#?

Comment: Are you trying to create the binding in c# code-behind instead of as a xaml declaration?

Comment: Have you at least tried anything? The XAML syntax for binding is not massively different to what you have already posted.

Comment: Added more information

Comment: That looks ok.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to create the same binding in C#.

```
var binding = new Binding("Oppervlak") {
    Source = Resources["Gegevens"], //assuming this code is being called from the Window class
    ValidateOnExceptions = true,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource
};
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that, Ive tried this and it seems that the UpdateSourceTrigger does not function. The field immediately produces an error that the input format is incorrect (it should be double) and when I enter a number it does not change.